# Failing to register and login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
     http://170.178.197.250/~devdegree/index.php
```

Using a form from phpacademy and feel free to visit the temp url and hopefully help me out here.

The problem is that there is a valid database connecting to this website, I enter the fields and it just stays on the register.php file.

Same applies when I create a user from the database itself then use that info to login and again the same problem applies.

This is about 2 years old and it worked for me last year and if there's any files you need to look at I'll reply with the script on here if need be but hopefully it's simply enough.

register.php

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
logged_in_redirect();
include 'includes/overall/header.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$required_fields = array('username', 'password', 'password_again', 'first_name', 'email');
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
        break 1;
    }
}

if (empty($errors) === true) {
    if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username \'' . $_POST['username'] . '\' is already taken';
    }
    if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) == true) {
        $errors[] = 'Your username must not contain any spaces.';
    }
    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
        $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters';
    }
    if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_again']) {
        $errors[] = 'Your passwords do not match';
    }
    if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'A valid email address is required';
    }
    if (email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, the email \'' . $_POST['email'] . '\' is already in use';
    }
    }
    }

    ?>
    <h1>Register</h1>

    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
    echo 'You\'ve been registered successfully! Please check your email to activate your                          account.';
    } else {
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $register_data = array(
        'username'      => $_POST['username'],
        'password'      => $_POST['password'],
        'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'],
        'email'         => $_POST['email'],
        'email_code'    => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime())
    );

    register_user($register_data);
    header('Location: register.php?success');
    exit();

    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo output_errors($errors);
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Username*:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username">
        </li>
        <li>
            Password*:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </li>
        <li>
            Password again*:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password_again">
        </li>
        <li>
            First name*:<br>
            <input type="text" name="first_name">
        </li>
        <li>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="last_name">
        </li>
        <li>
            Email*:<br>
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </li>
        </ul>
        </form>

        <?php 
        }
        include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Again, any other files (there's around 20+) then I'll have a look into showing you if it means you can understand and help me out.

Big thanks,

Dev.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see an `action` on your form to the `register.php`. Try adding one like "`action="register.php"`"

Answer (score 0):

Look from the current website you linked the form post correctly to register.php.
Nothing is not working.
You should check your machine for httpd ( or whatever are you using ) logs.
Maybe some warning or some fatalerror of php can explain the problem.
From this code and the website nothing looks wrong.